# Multithreaded correctness - Inconsistent synchronization

Tags: java, sonarqube, findbugs

Whats wrong with this...?

```
public final void setListValid(final List<ValidRes> listValidRes) {
    this.listValidRes = listValidRes;
}
```

Sonar yells me at:

`Inconsistent synchronization of xxx.listValidRes; locked 50% of time`

Does anyone know what things i need to do ?

Comment: I think there is a `p` missing.

Comment: All set now, sorry it was insancely long name.. did not wanted to make it confusing here.

Comment: I cannot see any synchronization in the code given in the question ... I guess you synchronize elsewhere in the code and *not* here ...

Comment: If all other usages of `this.listValidRes` are in a synchronized block, do so here or make the Interface "*not* Threadsafe" explicitly and don't synchronize. Then the client has to bother with threading... It's a design decision, but either way: you cannot mix. Synchronize or don't but not "sometimes".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The code given in the question has no synchronization. I assume that you synchronize on the `this.listValidRes` somewhere else in your code. And exactly that is what Sonar tells you: if you synchronize on a resource do so on *all* usages or don't do it at all and have someone else deal with it.

Basically it is a design decision:

- You can **chose to *not* synchronize** and have the client bother with it. The advantage is that without synchronization it will be significantly faster. So if your class is used in a single-threaded setup, it will be better to ditch synchronization. **But** document it clearly to be *not* threadsafe or a client *will* use it multithreaded and complain about weird errors...
- If you **chose to** (or have to) **synchronize, then do it on every usage of the critical resource**. There are different ways to achieve this. Maybe you want to show a usage of the resource that you in fact did synchronize. Maybe I or someone else can give you some good advice on that.